# SSRS IIF and Switch functions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a Report where I want to change the background color of the column(sales) based on  the Continent column values. Below is the continent column values.
[image]

I tried the following expression under Sales column( background color),

```
=IIF(Fields!column.Value ="4th Quarter",
 SWITCH (
                   Fields!continents.Value ="Asia", "Green",
                   Fields!continents.Value = "N America","LIMEGREEN",
                   Fields!continents.Value ="S America","Yellow",
                   Fields!continents.Value = "Europe", "Red"  
         )
, "Dummy Value")
```

When I preview the report, I can see only Green color for all the rows. I know Switch function in SSRS will return the first expression that it finds true.
I also tried by using only IIF condition, still same issue. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
=IIF((Fields!column.Value ="4th Quarter") AND (Fields!continents.Value ="Asia"),"Green",
     IIF((Fields!column.Value ="4th Quarter") AND (Fields!continents.Value = "N America"),"LIMEGREEN",
        IIF((Fields!column.Value ="4th Quarter") AND (Fields!continents.Value ="S America"),"Yellow",
            IIF((Fields!column.Value ="4th Quarter") AND (Fields!continents.Value = "Europe"), "Red",
            "Dummy Value"))))
```